# How to change which partial is rendered in OctoberCMS component?

Tags: php, octobercms, octobercms-plugins

By default, OctoberCMS plugin components render the partial `default.htm`. Is it possible to override which partial will be rendered? For example ...

Plugin file structure

```
├── components
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── default.htm
│   │   ├── other_partial.htm
│   ├── Example.php
├── ...
├── Plugin.php
```

Example.php

```php
class Example extends ComponentBase  {

   public function onRun() {
       // change the rendered partial, such that other_partial.htm
       // will be rendered instead of default.htm
       $this->setRenderedPartial('other_partial')
   }

}
```

I know that it is possible to render the `other_partial` from inside the `default.htm` but in my case I seek to leave the `default.htm` untouched and render the other partial as default instead.

Answer (score 2):

The way I would do this in October is to handle this on the page template with some logic in Twig. This would probably be the most logic place to put it in my opinion.

Comment: Can you give an example how to use the page template?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `renderPartial` method

```
public function onRun()
{
    $content = $this->renderPartial('default.htm');
}
```

doc: http://octobercms.com/docs/plugin/components#render-partial-method

Comment: Thanks, that's going in the right direction. However, the default markup would still be rendered, but I could include in the partial with some logic as Chris V suggested

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to solve this problem for my website, and I think I have found the answer. On your component PHP file, you can try this function:

```
public function onRender(){
    $partialType= $this->property('partialType');
    switch ($partialType) {
        case 'one':
            $partial = '@partial-1.htm';
            break;
        
        case 'two':
            $partial = '@partial-2.htm';
            break;

        case 'three':
            $partial = '@partial-3.htm';
            break;
              
        case 'four':
            $partial = '@partial-4.htm';
            break;
              
        default:
            $partial = '@default.htm';
            break;
    }

   return $this->renderPartial($partial);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should tell the component to render the Partial on `onRender()` that is run after the layout and page are rendered:

```
public function onRender()
{
    return $this->renderPartial('@other_partial');
}
```

Use the @ to force the component to look for a component partial instead of a theme one!

Answer (score 0):

The logic on you page template could look like the code below to decide which partial should be displayed.

Something like (you need to check the syntax, because I haven't used it recently:

```
{% if other %} #if variable 'other' exists in the page
    {% partial "other" %}
{% else %}
    {% partial "default" %}
{% endif %}
```

Of course, you need to have some logic in your page that either decides the variable 'other' should exist or not. Or you could make the logic check for a specific value of the control variable

Comment: Thanks, that would work. It has the downside that you can't "fork" the components default markup in the page editor (well you can but it would only give you this if logic). Anyway, it works!

Comment: Could you please explain what you mean in more detail?

Comment: In October you can [customize the default markup](http://octobercms.com/docs/cms/components#customizing-default-markup) in the page editor by clicking on the the little fork symbol which will load the default markup. In this case, the markup only contains again if-else-logic and not the actual partial code you want to customize. You can still copy it in manually, so it works, but my original question was looking for actually changing it - but I reckon it is not possible in October an logic in the partial is in fact the way to go.

Comment: Actually, you can have logic in the partial itself (except a component partial if I recall correctly). You can use twig too inside the partial

Answer (score 0):

I'm still looking for a solution that does not require twig. I added a setting in my component that list all files under the template folder.

Now I can choose the desired template file, I want that, when I simply call the component like that :

```
{% component 'mycomponent' %}
```

it render the component using the correct partial defined in the component settings.

There is probably some code to pu in the onRun() function of my component, but don't find the correct one.

Using $content = $this->renderPartial('grid.htm'); still render the default.htm partial...